# Replace brackets around words with something else using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have this text:

```
Lorem ipsum [!one] and [!two]
```

And I need to get to this text:

```
Lorem ipsum [one](http://example.com/one) and [two](http://example.com/two)
```

This code finds each word between "[!" and "]"

```
import re
r = r"\[\!(\w+)\]"

text = "Lorem ipsum [!one] and [!two]"

result = re.findall(r, text)
```

This gives me the following result

```
['one', 'two']
```

I could use `.replace()` but I was wondering if this is doable with regex.

Edit:

I needed the matched text to be processed a bit before replacing it. This is the solution using the answer as a starting point:

```
import re

def generate_url(input):
    # Do extra stuff here
    return "http://example.com/%s" % input

input = '''Lorem ipsum [!one] and [!two]'''
regex = "\[@([^]]+)\]"

url_generator = lambda match: "[%s](%s)" % (match.group(1), generate_url(match.group(1)))

output= re.sub(regex, url_generator, input)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `re.sub()` fro this purpose.

```
input = '''Lorem ipsum [!one] and [!two]'''
input = re.sub("\[!([^]]+)\]", '[\\1](http://example.com/\\1)', input)
```

`\\1` is the captured group from the regex matching `([^]]+)`

Comment: Note that `input` is not a good name for a variable - shadowing built-in.

Comment: It's OK for an example, not gonna use "input" as the var name in the code anyway :) Second line should be "output" but edit needs to be at least 6 characters different so I'll leave it like that.

Comment: @yoshi see also some info on [Raw string notation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#raw-string-notation).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [re.sub()](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Lorem ipsum [!one] and [!two]"
>>> re.sub(r"\[\!(\w+)\]", r'[\1](http://example.com/\1)', s)
'Lorem ipsum [one](http://example.com/one) and [two](http://example.com/two)'
```

`\1` is a reference for the captured group `(\w+)`.

Also see [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping) on capturing groups.